# Monitor scale on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, scale, azure-application-insights

I have a request pipeline that goes `app-service` > `app-service` > `cosmosDB` (then returns). We are currently in performance testing for said pipeline and hitting it with about 10k requests per minute. Something that we've noticed is that the longer the test goes on, the worse performance gets, so our response was to enable autoscale on the `app services` and on `cosmosDB`. Unfortunately, this hasn't impacted performance, and I'd like to see if the autoscale is even working.

**TL;DR**

Is there a log for how many instances of a resource are active [from autoscale] at a given time?

Comment: You can look at throughput consumption in the Insights tab in the portal and/or using Azure Monitor. My guess is this is due to thread starvation. Take a look at this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-dotnet-sdk-request-timeout?tabs=cpu-new#high-cpu-utilization.  Overall too, if you're doing this sort of testing I recommend you get your app instrumented with App Insights or similar tools and also get Azure Monitor setup.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/monitor?tabs=azure-diagnostics

Comment: Thanks, @MarkBrown. I'll read through the linked documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a log for how many instances of a resource are active [from autoscale] at a given time?]

Thanks @MarkBrown for the Comment.

I have created Azure App Service and enabled auto scale based on the request’s metric rule.
[image]

The dotted line shows the maximum request that will enable additional instances of app service whenever the web app reaches request of 70.53%. Blue line shows the current requests of the web app.

[image]

Whenever the app reaches `70%` increase the count by `1` with maximum instances up to `4`

[image]

- Added another rule for scale in
  [image]
- We can see the capacity is still `1`. Run the load test on Web App. You can see App service is scaled up to 3 instances after load test.
  [image]

[image]

- Check the Auto Scale history.

[image]

- View the Web apps activity history in `Azure monitor` =>`Activity Log`.
  [image]

***Autoscaling  in Cosmos DB***

- In Azure Cosmos DB Number of Ru’s are scaled. We can mention the max number of `RU’s` required for our `Cosmos DB`.

***Enabling Autoscale for the CosmosDB***

- Navigate to your `Azure Cosmos DB Account` => `Scale` => `New Container`.

[image]

- `Cosmos DB` will scale from `5000` to `1/10th` of its value (500-5000 RU's). If we work for more hours, scale will be up to the mark. When our workload is not running, we can scale down to less `RU's`.

***Check the consumption of RU’s in Metrics***

[image]

- Currently the percentage is 14%, Normalized RU consumption chart varies between `0-100 %` and it gives information on how much of the current throughput we have provisioned and is utilized.
- 100% means max RU that we have mentioned. If our consumption in the above chart is linear and above 66% on average, we don’t need autoscaling, if it is variable, we need to auto scale.

> And how to check how many instances does cosmos dB has scaled to after enabling auto scale?

Provisioned Throughput is the instances or scaling that cosmos dB has done. In the chart below auto scale has provisioned 500  throughputs

Auto scale max throughput –  1k

Provisioned Throughput- 500k

[image]

- We can also send `Azure cosmos DB` logs to `log analytics` to query and get additional insights.

[image]

[image]